# MySQL query performance tuning

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm trying to run a query over a table with around a 1 million records.
The structure of the table with its indexes is:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Name` varchar(510) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Latitude` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Longitude` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`Latitude`,`Longitude`,`Id`),
    KEY `IX_Latitude_Longitude` (`Latitude`,`Longitude`),
    KEY `IX_Latitude` (`Latitude`),
    KEY `IX_Longitude` (`Longitude`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT m.Id, m.Name, sqrt(69.1 * (m.Latitude - :latitude) * 69.1 * (m.Latitude - :latitude) +
                     53.0 * (m.longitude - :longitude) * 53.0 * (m.longitude - :longitude)) as Distance,
m.Latitude as Latitude, m.Longitude as Longitude
FROM table m
WHERE sqrt(69.1 * (m.Latitude - :latitude) * 69.1 * (m.Latitude - :latitude)
      + 53.0 * (m.longitude - :longitude) * 53.0 * (m.longitude - :longitude)) < :radius
ORDER BY  sqrt(69.1 * (m.Latitude - :latitude) * 69.1 * (m.Latitude - :latitude) +
          53.0 * (m.longitude - :longitude) * 53.0 * (m.longitude - :longitude)) desc
LIMIT 0, 100
```

That suppose to return all the records in a specific radius (distance calculation information: http://www.meridianworlddata.com/Distance-Calculation.asp)

BUT the query takes a lot of time...
Here is the explain plan that I get:

```
id|select_type |table|type|possible_keys|key   |key_len|ref   |rows   |Extra
1 |SIMPLE      |m    |ALL |{null}       |{null}|{null} |{null}|1264001|Using where; Using filesort
```

What am I doing wrong?
Which index do I need to add in order to cause the query to use it instead of table scan?
Do I need to change the table structure?

Comment: @GEOCHET, why did you add those unneded backticks?

Comment: do you have enough indexes on that table ? at least 2 are redundant so you can remove them: IX_Latitude_Longitude and IX_Latitude

Comment: @GEOCHET see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5492754/revisions

Comment: @nhnb: I have no idea what you are going on about. Like I already said, I didn't add the back ticks. Clearly, they are showing up now because the code formatting was fixed. It is obvious the code would have them in the first place as well. Why is this any of your concern anyway?

Comment: @nhnb There's a "view source" link for each revision. The backticks were definitely already there ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using functions inside your WHERE clause, so it will always result in a table scan. The database has no way to index against the result of a function. I think your best option is to come up with some way to limit the results before trying to evaluate the distance algorithm.

For instance, for a given location, you can know the minimum and maximum possible latitude that can fall within your set distance, so filter by that first. A degree of latitude is ~69 miles, so if your search radius is 50 miles, it would never be possible for anything more than 0.725 degrees of latitude away to fall within 50 miles of your location. Since this is just a numeric comparison `WHERE m.latitude > (:latitude - 0.725) AND m.latitude < (:latitude + 0.725)`, not a call to a function, the database will be able to use your indexes to evaluate it.

Longitude is more complicated, since the distance for each degree varies depending on how far north/south the location happens to be, but depending on how much work you want to put into it, you could do the same with longitude as well.

Comment: Yeah, do that. Also notice that latitude is the first part of your primary key, so a range scan on this is the best option (given than InnoDB clusters the primary key)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  
It would have worked if I wouldn't need to order the result by proximity, to the location that I'm passing. Now the order by clause is killing the query. I can't order only the result of the query because I want to return the 100 rows order by their proximity...

Comment: Assuming you're using a version of MySQL that supports subqueries (5.0+ does for sure), you would use a subquery in the FROM clause. So you would have an outer query where you order by the result of your distance formula, and an inner query where you "pre-filter" your results. If you're using a version of MySQL that doesn't support subqueries, then I'd recommend using a temp table and querying against that.